# Questions on DNA damage

Tags: dna, dna-damage

I'm not strong in biology, so bear with me on this:

I've been reading that as we age, our DNA is damaged by internal (e.g. errors during replication) and external (e.g. sun damage or radiation) factors.

- If you take, say, an 80 year old, can you find DNA in their body that's the same as when they were a newborn? What kind of cells would have undamaged DNA?
- Is DNA damage distributed evenly across the body or will some parts have more damage than others?
- Is there any published data on how much DNA damage an average person accumulates over their lifetime? I'm not sure how this can be quantified, but I'm wondering if there has been any study on gauging damage.

Comment: Since errors frequently occur during cell division, I guess cells that divide less frequently (e.g. mature neurons do not divide at all) will probably have less damage. Some cells not only divide fast, but also become polypoloid (e.g. liver cells), so these cells probably can tolerate a lot of mutations.

Comment: Also, this new article may be of interest [DNA mutation clock proves tough to set](http://www.nature.com/news/dna-mutation-clock-proves-tough-to-set-1.17079). Apparently, rates with which mutations accumulate over human generations may be fluctuating!

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question!

1. You would definitely be able to find quite a few *sequences* of DNA that are undamaged (in fact most of them would be undamaged), but it is very unlikely that any cells in his/her body would have a perfect copy of the entire original genome.
2. I'm sure that cells closer to the skin (exposed to more radiation) would have more mutations, but beyond that most everything depends on where you live, your habits, etc. (if you're a smoker you will obviously have more mutations in your lung cells).
3. Under regular circumstances (low levels of mutagens), about 3 nucleotide mutations occur in the human genome per cell per division (DNA replication) (from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26881/). The rest of the math would be a very rough estimate, seeing as you'd need to make a lot of assumptions (cell division rate average, other mutagens an organism may encounter, life span, the list goes on), but however you want to do it, there's the number you need to start with.

I hope this helps.

CDB

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Regarding the first question, is it possible to use multiple DNA samples and compare them to one another to derive the entire original genome? The goal would be to identify damaged sequences and replace them with the undamaged ones from other samples since I assume a single block of DNA is unlikely to be corrupt in every single sample. I think a similar concept is implemented in cryptography and data storage in computers to achieve integrity.

Comment: @Mark13426 Sure. See e.g. this [PLoS Computational Biology paper](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003297) and references therein. Often the aim in these studies is to map cell lineages rather than infer the genotype of the fertilized egg, but the information is there if you wanted to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would identify which sequences were the original, undamaged sequences unless you had a reference (such as a map of the organism's genome when it was an embryo), but it would be very possible to retrieve an entire complete and undamaged genome from perhaps only a few hundred cells if you could identify the original DNA. May I ask what your project is regarding? It sounds very fascinating!

Comment: @CDB It's not generally true that cells closer to the skin have more mutations; what matters more than e.g. UV exposure is the number of cell generations that a cell goes through. Intestinal epithelium turns over rapidly and can have up to an order of magnitude greater number of cell generations than other tissues, resulting in a higher number of accumulated mutations over the lifetime.

Comment: Very true, however skin cells would be much more prone to mutations from radiation and radiation is a much more deadly mutagen than just mistakes made inside the cell itself seeing as radiation actually destroys the nucleotide.

Comment: @Mark13426 I apologize, I just realized something that you said in your comment. Comparing the cell genomes themselves to find the original genome without a map of it would be possible. It would just be very extremely difficult.

Comment: @CDB Regarding radiation leading to higher rates of mutation in epidermis than in more rapidly proliferating tissues: is do you have evidence for that, or is that just a hunch? Because in mouse, it goes in the opposite direction. And liver tissue, with its high exposure to mutagens, accumulates vastly more mutations than epidermis.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I'm not involved in any project. Over the last year, I've been interested in the study of aging. The older I get, the more I think about death, so I have a personal interest in why we age and whether it's preventable. With regards to genome preservation, I've been asking myself whether it makes sense to get my genome sequenced (not sure if this is commercially possible) and use the data in the future if future medicine can take advantage of it. Sounds like genome reconstruction is difficult, so why not map out whatever I have now while I'm healthy? Sorry, if I sound silly.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a number of questions here, but yes -- mutation rates have been studied extensively in humans as well as in model organisms. And as you suggest, they vary substantially across tissues. One starting point to read about how mutation rates are measured and how they vary across species, tissues, etc., is a 2010 [*Trends in Genetics* review](http://www.indiana.edu/~lynchlab/PDF/Lynch183.pdf) by Mike Lynch. See particularly Table 1.